# How do you break a dataframe into uneven segments based on the difference between index values exceeding a certain magnitude?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have done a terrible job of the title, but I don't know how else to phrase it in one sentence. Please bear with me. I'm not even sure this is possible.

I have a pandas dataframe that lists daily percentage changes in the value of an object. The objects are in columns, the percentage changes are in each row. The index of each row is a specific date. The dates are not consecutive. Sometimes they are all together, often the weekends are omitted, but occasionally, the dates skip whole weeks, or whole months, or even whole years. I want to iterate over chunks of a dataframe where the index difference is greater than 5 days. For example, the starting dataframe might look something like this

```
               THING_1     THING_2
DATE
1995-05-01   -0.006075   -0.003453
1995-05-02    0.003544    0.001997
1995-05-04    0.001234    0.003578
1995-08-28    0.002194   -0.000344
1995-08-31    0.005949    0.005178
1995-09-01    0.000429    0.008309
1995-09-02    0.001247   -0.000175
1995-09-03    0.011901    0.011502
```

I want to break it into chunks like this:

```
               THING_1     THING_2
DATE
1995-05-01   -0.006075   -0.003453
1995-05-02    0.003544    0.001997
1995-05-04    0.001234    0.003578


               THING_1     THING_2
DATE
1995-08-28    0.002194   -0.000344
1995-08-31    0.005949    0.005178


               THING_1     THING_2
DATE
1995-09-01    0.000429    0.008309
1995-09-02    0.001247   -0.000175
1995-09-03    0.011901    0.011502
```

This way I can iterate through the three chunks to ultimately calculate a period return for those specific sections. I think that this is going to be the most efficient method, because I can use a numpy function to calculate the ultimate period return, but if you think you can come up with a more efficient method becuase I'll have to loop through my dataframe to create these chunks, then I'm more than open to that.

Comment: I have simplified my answer below, and it doesn't contain loop. You could try it and compare the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
# Just in case cast time.

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

df['lag'] = df['DATE'] - df['DATE'].shift(1)

idx_gaps = list(df[df['lag'] > pd.Timedelta('5days')].index)
idx_gaps.insert(0, 0)
idx_gaps.append(len(df))

df['chunk_id'] = np.NaN

for i, idx in enumerate(idx_gaps[:-1]):
    if idx < idx_gaps[i + 1] + 1:
        df.loc[idx:idx_gaps[i + 1] + 1, 'chunk_id'] = i

for id_gr, gr in df.groupby('chunk_id'):
    print('found chunk', id_gr)
    print(gr)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted your question. It's somewhat more complicated than that. If you don't get the answer soon, I'll write down the correction.

Comment: @ScottBoston those two are supposed to be together, merging across months is desired, so long as the days between aren't more than 5.

Comment: I'm trying out your solution now, but it's throwing errors "Cannot shift with no freq"

Comment: I can't shift the index like that since it is entirely irregular. I think what you do there is to just shift all the original index values by one day, which means that the difference will always be 1, right? To make it easier, I was able to calculate the difference in days and have it listed as a column called 'DAYS_DELTA'

Comment: I added another row to show that the days being offset by 1 isn't necessarily the case, that they can be separated by up to 4 days, hence the >5 day group condition

Comment: Please take a look at the correction. I tried it with some mock-up, and it seems working.

Comment: I'm running it now, but it seems to take a really long time. I was hoping not to have to loop. The dataframe can have more than 50k rows; the rest of my manipulations are vectorized.

Comment: It seems really weird that this works slow. I do the stuff like this every day with the tables of similar sizes, and it takes seconds. Notice that the last for-loop is of course not mandatory, you can proceed with processing it in a normal groupwise manner.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a column to find difference and another column for cumulative sum

1. reset index of dataframe

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

the dataframe now looks like (I added one more row)

```
DATE    THING_1     THING_2
0   1995-05-01  -0.006075   -0.003453
1   1995-05-02  0.003544    0.001997
2   1995-08-12  0.002194    -0.000344
3   1995-08-28  0.002194    -0.000344
4   1995-08-31  0.005949    0.005178
5   1995-09-01  0.000429    0.008309
6   1995-09-02  0.001247    -0.000175
7   1995-09-03  0.011901    0.011502
```

2. convert `DATE` to `datetime` object

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

3. create a diff column

```
df['diff'] = (df['DATE'].shift(1).dt.year != df['DATE'].dt.year) | (df['DATE'].shift(1).dt.month != df['DATE'].dt.month) | (df['DATE'] - df['DATE'].shift(1) > pd.Timedelta('5days'))
```

4. create a `rank` column

```
df['rank'] = df['diff'].cumsum()
```

5. Finally split your dataframe

```
dfs = [x for _, x in df.groupby(['rank'])]
```

which will give you an array of dataframe as follows

```
[        DATE   THING_1   THING_2   diff  rank
 0 1995-05-01 -0.006075 -0.003453   True     1
 1 1995-05-02  0.003544  0.001997  False     1,
         DATE   THING_1   THING_2  diff  rank
 2 1995-08-12  0.002194 -0.000344  True     2,
         DATE   THING_1   THING_2   diff  rank
 3 1995-08-28  0.002194 -0.000344   True     3
 4 1995-08-31  0.005949  0.005178  False     3,
         DATE   THING_1   THING_2   diff  rank
 5 1995-09-01  0.000429  0.008309   True     4
 6 1995-09-02  0.001247 -0.000175  False     4
 7 1995-09-03  0.011901  0.011502  False     4]
```

6. drop unnecessary columns